# How can I assign randomly my midi inputs in ableton / maxmsp

Tags: midi, ableton-live, midi-controller-keyboard

I'd like to have a litlle program that would assign randomly (or partially randomly) my midi cc (from external keyboards and other midi devices) in Ableton and/or max msp.

Basically, every (or part) of my midi input would trigger every (or part) parameters assignables of my project in a random way.

Before get myself deepened in the codage a such thing, I'll be happy to know if anyone know a already made solution or if anyone has allready try and could give some tips on how to proceed.

Best,e

Comment: I'm not sure, if I understand you question correctly. I understand, that you want to use a midi input device (keyboard, drum-set etc.) not to make music, but to use it to feed this data into a random number generator to make its output less predictable. If I am right, then your question is off-topic here, because this site is about making and understanding music. Google for »hardware random number generator "midi"«. If I'm wrong, please clarify your question.

Comment: Dear @HubertSchölnast, there is a misunderstanding. Basically, I have midi devices with knobs. I like to assign my knobs to parameters of vst such as cutoff, resonance, attack and so on. I would like to instead doing this midi assignment job manually, have something that randomize this midi assignment. It would, fortunately, lead to happy and creative accident! :) My apologises if even after this new explanation it is still confusing and off-topic.